# Интеграция IBM Watson

Tags: java, облако, ibm

Всем привет. Кто нибудь работал с Ibm Cloud или Watson? Попытаюсь пояснить суть с помощью картинок. Есть вот такой стек:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Node1 - Web-server обрабатывающий запросы;
- Node2 - Клиент на котором стоит ПО для автоматизации (бот) в котором интегрирована [библиотека](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk) для коннекта и управления IBM Watson и все это на Java;
- Node3 - IBM Cloud, [IBM Watson Comunity](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developer/);

Мне необходимо сделать вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Node1 - Web-server обрабатывающий запросы;
- Node3 - IBM Cloud, [IBM Watson Comunity](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developer/) и здесь же в облаке расположить исходники этого "бота";

Процесс интеграции бота из Ibm Watson Comunity на сайт я нашел в [документации](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/curl.html?curl#introduction) но у меня иная ситуация.

1. А вот с помощью какой тулзы создать свое небольшое приложение, а точнее как мне там развернуть свое ПО? - я не понял. Т.к. клиент не желает держать модуль `bot app` на Ноде1
2. Как вариант, использовать bluemix app о котором пишут [здесь](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/cl-chatapp-bluemix-app/), [здесь](https://habr.com/company/ibm/blog/323006/), [здесь](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/cl-bluemixfoundry/index.html) и еще бог знает где, но в этом случае, как я понял из доков - мне придется уходить от java.

Заранее благодарен за ответ и рекомендации по данному вопросу.

Comment: Вы хотите разместить бота в облачном Ватсоне? Почему нельзя использовать свое серверное приложение для передачи ватсону запросов от вашего приложения?